# Change URL of plugin admin menu

Tags: admin-menu

Gravity Forms adds a Admin Menu called Entries that points to page=gf_entries. I am trying to modify this URL so that it defaults to page=gf_entries&id=2 instead. Below is the order of my WordPress Admin Menu. How can I update the URL of the Entries menu item?

```
Dashboard
Posts
Media
Forms
-Forms
-New Form
-Entries
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution -

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse_admin_menu', 100 );
function wpse_admin_menu()
{
    global $menu, $submenu;
    $parent = 'gf_edit_forms';
    if( !isset($submenu[$parent]) )
        return;

    foreach( $submenu[$parent] as $k => $d ){
        if( $d['2'] == 'gf_entries' )
        {
            $submenu[$parent][$k]['2'] = 'admin.php?page=gf_entries&id=2';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly except I get an access denied vs clicking on the org link them the ID. Any ideas?

Comment: The menu item stop be active.

Answer (score 0):

The "Access denied" gave me a headache actually. It seems to be a gravity forms issue, maybe something with callback, i dont know.
Even doing:

```
unset($submenu['gf_edit_forms']['2']);
```

breaks thye permissions down.

I managed to add new Entries Button and hide previous one by css
(which is kind of workaround i guess)

The only drawback is that "Entries" is not Bold while you are on the Entries Page (You could probably give some more CSS to it but i don';t acually mind)

It goes like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_addon_navigation', 'add_menu_item' );
function add_menu_item( $menu_items ) {
    $menu_items[] = array( "name" => "gf_entries&id=2", "label" => "Entries", "callback" => "gf_entries&id=2", "permission" => "gform_full_access" ); //edit_posts
    return $menu_items;
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    #toplevel_page_gf_edit_forms > ul > li:nth-child(4){
        display:none !important;
    }
  </style>';
}
```